# Excel INDIRECT function referencing cell with variable row from another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I cannot get the `INDIRECT` Excel function to reference a cell from another worksheet.

I've tried many variations of the following formula but always get an error

```
=INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!""C"&D13)
```

also

```
=INDIRECT("'"Form Responses 1'"!""C"&D13)
```

I'm trying to get data from Column `C` on Worksheet 'Form Responses 1' – with Row variable in cell `D13` [I can put the cell `D13` (row variable) on either worksheet which ever is more convenient for the formula] to my destination Worksheet (into cell `C2` on the destination worksheet) I put the formula above in `C2` on my destination worksheet.

I can write formulas for `INDIRECT` function that work on the same worksheet and formulas for moving a cell from one worksheet to another but cannot get `INDIRECT` function to work from one worksheet to another with the variable row.

Answer (score 2):

Your first try is close, but it has some extraneous quotes:

```
=INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!""C"&D13)
                              ↑↑
```

You should do this:

```
=INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!C"&D13)
```